# Consolidate font-files while supporting IE

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, webfonts

I have quite a few fonts right now that I need to use for my site:

```
fonts/
├── Knockout-30.otf
├── Verlag-Black.otf
├── Verlag-Bold.otf
├── Verlag-Book.otf
├── Verlag-Light.otf
├── VerlagCond-Black.otf
└── VerlagCond-Bold.otf
```

Right now my `css` looks like:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Knockout';
  src: url('fonts/Knockout-30.otf') format('opentype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Verlag';
  src: url('fonts/Verlag-Book.otf') format('opentype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Verlag';
  src: url('fonts/Verlag-Bold.otf') format('opentype');
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Verlag';
  src: url('fonts/Verlag-Light.otf') format('opentype');
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'VerlagBlack';
  src: url('fonts/Verlag-Black.otf') format('opentype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'VerlagCond';
  src: url('fonts/VerlagCond-Black.otf') format('opentype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'VerlagCond';
  src: url('fonts/VerlagCond-Bold.otf') format('opentype');
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Right now these fonts are not supported by IE apparently so I'm looking at using https://onlinefontconverter.com/ to generate IE friendly font file types. It seems a bit gross to me that I'd have to make 7 calls for font files. Is there a good standard in regards to consolidating these files so I would somehow only need to make one call? Or at least consolidate the similar font family types? I was recommended base64 encoding everything and including in the `css` but I know base64 increases file size from what I gather so I'm not sure if that trade would be worth it. Any advice is much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, but below is a standard way of calling `@font-face`

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 100;
  src: local("Roboto Thin Italic"), local("Roboto-ThinItalic"),
       url(../fonts/Roboto/Roboto-ThinItalic.woff2) format("woff2"), 
       url(../fonts/Roboto/Roboto-ThinItalic.woff) format("woff"), 
       url(../fonts/Roboto/Roboto-ThinItalic.ttf) format("truetype"), 
       url(../fonts/Roboto/Roboto-ThinItalic.eot), 
       url(../fonts/Roboto/Roboto-ThinItalic.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"),
       url(../fonts/Roboto/Roboto-ThinItalic.svg#Roboto) format("svg");
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  src: local("Roboto Thin"), local("Roboto-Thin"), 
       url(../fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Thin.woff2) format("woff2"), 
       url(../fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Thin.woff) format("woff"), 
       url(../fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Thin.ttf) format("truetype"), 
       url(../fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Thin.eot),
       url(../fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Thin.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"),
       url(../fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Thin.svg#Roboto) format("svg");
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}
...
```

---

**font-family** - *defining a global name*
**font-style** - *defining the font style of the font file*
**font-weight** - *defining the font weight of the font file*
**src** - *defining paths*
**unicode-range** - *well, this is optional: you ignore this line if you don't know*

So basically you will have to do this repeatedly for all the font types & weights, unless you have all the font types contain in a single font file. So by defining these separately it will be easy for the browser to pick up the required font file. So you will just have to define the font-style & weight for the child elements, and browser will decide which file to pick. So there are no other options than defining them all.

---

***If you don't want to call multiple files,***

you can simply call the font like this and font-style & font-weight will render by the browser instead of files (NOTE: *This might cause some anti-aliasing issues*)

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: local("Roboto"),
       url(../fonts/Roboto/Roboto.woff2) format("woff2"), 
       url(../fonts/Roboto/Roboto.woff) format("woff"), 
       url(../fonts/Roboto/Roboto.ttf) format("truetype"), 
       url(../fonts/Roboto/Roboto.eot), 
       url(../fonts/Roboto/Roboto.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"),
       url(../fonts/Roboto/Roboto.svg#Roboto) format("svg");
}
```

To get a better idea read: https://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-css3-fonts-20090618/

Comment: So this will help support IE for me. Which I was using https://onlinefontconverter.com/ for. My big problem is if there's a way to consolidate all of the files so I don't have a separate italic and normal file. If there is a way to use the same one.

Comment: Well, that depends on the font file. If the font file contains both italic & normal, you might able to. But may I know the reason you want to consolidate the importing? Because if you want to reduce the writing, you can use a css preprocessor like LESS or SCSS.

Comment: Also see my update answer. And yes you can get the font files converted by: https://onlinefontconverter.com/

Comment: I'm already using sass. The reason I want to consolidate font files is because if I have two font types like italic and normal, that's two calls to the server the client has to make for each font. Ideally I'd only want one file to reduce that. My main goal is to lower page load time.

Comment: Well, that is not possible. If you want to call separate files, there will be separate calls somehow. So you will have 2 options, one is to edit the font using a tool like font-forge and have all the font styles pack to a single or use a normal font style and allow browser to render the font-style (see my edited answer above). So it will be a single call.

Comment: And also note that when you define `@font-face` the call will only goes to the requested font styles by the css. So there won't be a problem if you use few from the font styles. As it will call only used styles.

Comment: And as I answered above by using the same name for the font e.g. `font-family: "Roboto"`, it is consolidating the font using css level. Hope this is clear! :)

Comment: Sucks there's not a clean automated way to do what font forge does. Oh well. Thanks for your help! Cheers!